# Project developed in VS 2012 but I want to open with VS 2008 Plese help me

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Project developed in VS 2010 but I want  to open the solution with VS 2008 Please help me..
 It throwing alert message as "**The selected file is solution file,but was created by newser version of this application cannot be opened**"

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question text. Was the solution created with VS2012 or VS2010?

Comment: Similar Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758751/visual-studio-wont-open-solution-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert a VS 2010 soultion back to 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898325/how-to-convert-a-vs-2010-soultion-back-to-2008)

Answer (score 3):

There are two steps to use VS 2010 project in VS 2008
Step 1:

You need to copy the folders, cs and aspx file that what you have added in vs 2010 except solution and config file.

Step 2:

You need to create a new empty project in vs 2008 and paste the file inside the solution.

Don't replace any files, you will have some errors in namespaces add the dll in the reference folder for avoiding those errors.