# Upgrading a C# project from VS2010 to VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configuration, visual-studio-2012

I have a  product in VS2010 using Winform  that is composed of multiple multi-project solutions.  I need to port this to VS2012. Why you might ask?  because we need to use the WF4.5 features.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Is it as easy as installing VS2012 and opening the solutions in vs2012 and compile and link?

Comment: Your project currently is running on which Framework? see this [SO Question and links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143383/converting-vs2012-solution-to-vs2010)

Comment: @Mark Hall:  Thanks for your reply but I did not find my answer in the links that you provided. I am upgrading from 2010 to 2012. In th elink that you provided the issue is going from 2012 to 2010.  Although I tried to reverse the answers it did not help.

Comment: In all of the projects that I have converted, they have just worked. The only point of issue would be the differences between the 4.5 and 4.0 Framework. I would be sure to exercise your program completely to make sure you are not having any problems with an edge case. see [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=VS.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** You may upgrade your VS2010 project to VS2012, however Windows forms applications will not explicitly upgraded.

**Option #1:** If you still want to keep the WinForm project and not convert it to the WPF application then you have to use WF4.5 features through services.

**Option #2:** Although Microsoft removed the option to create a C++/CLI Windows Forms application, the template files are still installed. The only thing missing seems to be the .vsz files and a registration in the vcNET.vcdir file. I have recreated these files and put them up for download [here](http://www.t-hart.org/vs2012/).

Install the files and you should be able to create WinForm apps in C++/CLI again.

**Option #3:** You may still upgrade your projects separately according to this post - [FREE: Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FREEVisualStudioExpress2012ForWindowsDesktop.aspx).

My advice **before upgrading** to .NET4.5, would be check all your third party components, and make sure that they have updates for upgraded version of framework.

Comment: @EIYusubov : Thanks for your reply. But my poroject is in C# not C++ or CLI (i am not sure what is CLI).  Can I still use your reply or your reply just applies to C++ and CLI.  Thanks.

Comment: According to this post it should work - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FREEVisualStudioExpress2012ForWindowsDesktop.aspx