# Visual Studio 2010 is unable to open project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I used Visual Studio 2010 to develop a web application. I formatted my machine and installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional. When I try to open old projects, I get an error saying:

> The selected file is a solution file, but was created by a newer version of this application and cannot be opened.

I do not remember the version of visual studio 2010 I used the first time.
Can anyone tell me which version came after the professional edition?

Comment: Try downloading the VS 2012 express version and open your solution/project in it.

Comment: This normally means it was created by VS2012 or VS2013.

Comment: thanx for your response but i did create them in visual studio 2010

Comment: Try downloading service packs for VStudio or download VStudio 2010 Ultimate or VStudio 2012, 2013

Comment: Try following [this anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17671091/2174170)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you had a service pack installed that you are missing with a clean installation.

Comment: Thanx Sam, it worked after updating to the latest service pack

Answer (score 3):

Open the .sln file in a text editor. In the beginning there is a marker which tells the VS version it is meant for. For VS 2010 it should look like that:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

You should be able to change these values without any problems. As far as I know the file format did not change.

**EDIT**

Considering the comment of Dumisani: of course you need to target .net 4.0 and make sure no features of .net 4.5 are used!

Comment: Editing this line will actually work to allow VS 2010 to read solution files created/edited with VS2012; I've done this.

Comment: Probably not the best idea though. They are not compatible as standard for a reason.

Comment: @Rondles I did it several times for VS2012 and VS2013. So far I did not encounter any problems

Comment: @toATwork Not saying you're guaranteed to get one, but you could end up running into an issue which could be very hard if not impossible to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure VS2010 is updated to the latest service pack, otherwise check to see if the project was actually made in VS2012/13 in which case you will need to create a new VS2010 solution and rebuild it from your existing projects.

Comment: Thanx BenM, it worked after updating to the latest service pack