# 2013 VS code dosent open in VS 2010 after changing the settings on the code and gives various errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've created a web client and web service  in Visual Studio 2013 and the university I'm at uses 2010 and it won't open! It mentions something about NET Framework 4.5. How can I convert my project so it will open in 2010? I need to sort this ASAP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMechGLSService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMechGLSService" contract="MechGLSReference.IMechGLSService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IMechGLSService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: VS2010 doesn't support 4.5. Downgrade the project if you really need to open it.

Comment: I tried that link thing, but only one project is opening in 2010 out of 2 and another one says "unable to read the project file example.csproj"

Comment: Just change the target framework, and hope you didn't use any 4.5-specific language features. The linked question you're duplicating covers how to do that.

Comment: I tried doing that but the problem is that only one project is uploading out of two, the second project says "unable to read the project file xyz.csproj"

Comment: You have to update each project. You might have to remove and re-add the reference to project #2, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: I did upgrade each of the project, but the issue is in one the app.config I don't find:                  sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"
to

sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"

Comment: Alternatively consider just getting 2013 [Express edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) instead...

Comment: I have added the "App.config" code where  sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" to sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0 isnt present

Comment: This is the error I get                                              "Unable to read the project 'Mech_GLS_ServiceLibrary.csproj'. C:\Users\Desktop\walmart\Common\StgDir-DMS\HostWebService\host_webservice\source‌​\StagigngWeb\Mech_GLS_ServiceLibrary\Mech_GLS_ServiceLibrary\Mech_GLS_ServiceLibr‌​ary.csproj(64,3):The imported project "C:\Progrean Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Servi‌​ceModel.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in <Import> declaration is correct, and the files exist on disk"

Answer (score 0):

In your project in 2013. Right click the **Project** and click on **Properties**. When the new "page" opens up, you'll see, on the left part of your screen a tab that says Application. On that tab you should see your assembly name and another label that says **Target Framework**. Under that you should be able to open a drop-down list and click on **.NET Framework 4.0**[image]

http://locktar.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/change-target-framework-version-for-all-the-projects-in-the-solution/

Comment: I did change the target framework

Comment: This is the error I get Unable to read the project 'Mech_GLS_ServiceLibrary.csproj'. C:\Users\Desktop\walmart\Common\StgDir-DMS\HostWebService\host_webservice\source\StagigngWeb\Mech_GLS_ServiceLibrary\Mech_GLS_ServiceLibrary\Mech_GLS_ServiceLibrary.csproj(64,3):The imported project "C:\Progrean Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in <Import> declaration is correct, and the files exist on disk.

Comment: Did you rebuild it in 2013?

Comment: No I am trying to open the project in VS 2010 and its giving m that error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405108/visual-studio-2012-project-wont-open-in-2010

Go check this out, it will give you 3 steps. And for the record, I'd still rebuild it after you change all of this in 2013.

Comment: i did all the 3 steps but still its throwing error

Comment: In one of my project the 2nd Step dosent exist, see my code posted above ie "App.config"

Comment: Tbh, I would just open visual studio 2010 and just go into the File/WindowExplorer and highlight-drag them into a new folder and just add the files individually to the project that way.