# Not able to open the sample in VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have created the wpf sample in VS2012 with framework version as 4.0. Then I tried to open that sample in VS2010 in another machine that does not contains VS2012 and framework 4.5 but the sample not opening and throws error. I don't know the reason.

**Error Message:**

> To Run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .Net Framework:
>   .Net Framework, Version=4.5

Any one please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: valuable suggestion: include error message in your question.

Comment: You have to downgrade, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143383/converting-vs2012-solution-to-vs2010

Comment: Is **To Run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .Net Framework: .Net Framework, Version=4.5** not clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

Well, because it hasn't ever been possible to open projects created with a later version of Visual Studio with an older version...

You can not open VS2010 projects with VS2008 and you can not open VS2008 projects with VS2005 etc. If you create a project with VS2012, you'll need to open it with 2012 or later.

What you can do is create a new project in VS2010 and then add the source files. Or think about installing VS 2012 ;-)

---

I doubt that your sample is really compiled against .NET 4.5. From your edit I take it that you're trying to *run* the EXE you compiled from your project? Of course when you create a .NET 4.5 project, .NET 4.5 **must** be installed to run the application!

Comment: Thorsten-I have created the sample in VS2012 against framework 4.0 only. Then why it is not running in VS2010(framework 4.0)?

Comment: As I said: A) You can not open VS2012 projects in VS2010 (downgrading projects is not possible) B) I doubt that you actually selected .NET 4.0 as the project's target. Otherwise it would not ask for .NET 4.5 to be installed - maybe one of the project's dependencies is built for 4.5 only?