# To open a visual studio 2013 project with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I need to open a Visual studio 2013 project  with Visual studio 2010. It is possible ?
Thanks.

I tried  but  It generate  a compatibility error.

my project is a MVC4 solution

thanks a lot for yours answers

Comment: Can you give us some more information on what type of project you're trying to open? WinForms, Web, etc ...

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143383/converting-vs2012-solution-to-vs2010/13458225#13458225

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143383/converting-vs2012-solution-to-vs2010/13458225#13458225

Answer (score 6):

1st you have to download and install MVC 4 for Visual Studio 2010. you can download it using this link ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683 )

Then open your solution file in notepad. Make these 2 changes

1) Replace "Format Version 13.00" with "Format Version 11.00" (without quotes.)

2) Replace "# Visual Studio 2013" with "# Visual Studio 2010" (without quotes.)

This will solve your problem. If you still get an incompatible error, try following change also.

3) if you had .NET 4.5 selected as the default .NET version in your VS2013 project and your VS2010 environment does not support that.
To fix that, open the VS2013 .csproj file in a text editor and change the TargetFrameworkVersion down to 4.0 (from 4.5 or 4.5.2). VS2010 will then happily load the "edited" solution and projects.

You'll also have to edit an app.config files that have references to .NET 4.5 in a similar way to allow them to run on a .NET 4.0 environment.

Thatz worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh266747%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), it all depends.  You can't use certain framework and language features from a 2013 project in VS 2010.

This is from the document:

> If you use Visual Studio 2013 together with Visual Studio 2012 or
>   Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you can create and modify projects and files
>   in any of the three versions. You can transfer projects and files
>   among the versions as long as you don't add features that are not
>   supported by one of the versions.

Comment: my project  is a MVC 4 Solution, and I need to open and compile with  VS 2010 ...  I  worked  with VS 2013  test version , but trial licence  is  ending.

Thanks a lot for  you help.

Answer (score -3):

You can't. Visual Studio 2010 SP1 supports only MVC 2 and MVC 3.  See compatibility matrix (look at Scott Wylie's response).  You can open most projects with Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013, but there are some exceptions.  They are all highlighted in the matrix

Comment: This is not true! Check the download here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683