# Error message while trying to open VS 2010 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am getting an error message while trying to open a VS 2010 solution file in VS 2010. Error message- "THE SELECTED FILE IS A SOLUTION FILE, BUT IT WAS CREATED BY A NEWER VERSION OF THE APPLICATION AND CANNOT BE OPENED". I searched in web but was not successful. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been created with a newer version of VS so you need to edit the solution file. This answer has the steps to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13458225/1032258

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once. I opened a solution with dll files that were created using Windows 8.1 (with the same VS version I had) and I was using Windows 8. The error message was the same as you state.

The solution was to build the libraries on Windows 8, so you can use it for development in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.

I hope this helps.